# Android: How to set text color for list items in AlertDialog properly

Tags: android, themes, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` in my application. It contains a list of custom views with `TextView` widgets inside. Everything works fine on Android 2.x. The `AlertDialog` is created with white list and black text in it. But when I run my app on Android 3.x devices all `TextView`s are black and list's background is black too. So I can't see the text until I tap and hold one of the items.

Here's a `TextView`'s definition from the layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse" />
```

I thought that using `textAppearanceSmallInverse` for the `textAppearance` attribute is a proper way to set text parameters and it must work on all devices but seems I was wrong. So what should I do to make `AlertDialog` display list items properly on all platforms? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is fairly old, but maybe somebody else will benefit from this. The solution is to leverage Android's built-in resource selection to achieve what you're looking for. See [this](http://kmansoft.com/2011/10/15/alertdialog-custom-listview-items-and-honeycomb/) tutorial for instructions.

Comment: I used exactly the same approach in my project, but hoped a better solution existed.

Comment: I haven't seen your answer, but if you post it I'll accept it.

Comment: My comment above was taken from my answer.

Comment: Maybe you posted a comment instead of the answer somehow?

Comment: I can still see the answer but it is red and there is a message saying it was converted to a comment.  In any case, if this is the accepted answer I just hope that somebody searching later will see it.

Comment: I think moderators could remove your answer because you just posted a link to a blog. If you edit the answer and add a summary of that article, I'll accept your answer and it will help other people even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to leverage Android's built-in resource selection system.  You should specify two different styles and place them in the proper folders based on the API version.  Note that the following examples are not mine, I took them from [this](http://kmansoft.com/2011/10/15/alertdialog-custom-listview-items-and-honeycomb/) tutorial.

`res/values-v4/styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

<!-- Text for listboxes, inverted for Andorid prior to 3.0 -->

<style name="MyListTextAppearanceSmall">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse</item>
</style>

<style name="MyListTextAppearanceDefault">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceInverse</item>
</style>

<style name="MyListTextAppearanceMedium">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

`res/values-v11/styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Text for listboxes, non-inverted starting with Android 3.0 -->

    <style name="MyListTextAppearanceSmall">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyListTextAppearanceDefault">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyListTextAppearanceMedium">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then, in your `TextView`, specify the style like so:

```
<TextView
    android:style="@style/MyListTextAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

See the tutorial linked above for a lengthier explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for the popup dialog should look similar to this:

```
// Sets dialog for popup dialog list
AlertDialog dialog;
String[] items = {"exampleItem"};
ListAdapter itemlist = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setAdapter(itemlist, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
    {
    }
});
dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Here, you are getting the listview and setting the background color to white. If you want to change the color of the text for each of the textviews then you need to define their color in the layout of the textview, in this case black:

```
android:textColor="#000000"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't want to change list's background. I want it look like it should look on a particular platform. All I want is to set a proper text style to make it readable on every platform.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer seems like a bit of overkill. I simply forced the inverse background by calling:

```
dialogBuilder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
```

solves the problem just fine.

Comment: As far as I remember this flag doesn't solve the problem on both Android 2.x and Android 3.x.

Comment: setInverseBackgroundForced is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because you aren't specifying a theme, then it falls back to the default theme. In 2.x this should be Theme.Black and in 3.x Theme.Holo (or Theme.Light, not sure on this). Then `textAppearanceSmallInverse` resolves to different style in each theme.

Comment: I'm using 'Theme' in 2.x and 'Theme.Holo' in 3.x. But The problem is that the 'AlertDialog' uses opposite styles on different platforms. But both platforms use the same style for the title text. That's weird behavior.